# Hazelcast log4j configuration produces "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger" error

Tags: java, windows, log4j, hazelcast, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to setup Hazelcast log4j logging on Windows using the latest version.

I added the config:

```
  <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j</property>
  </properties>
```

I run the following command from the hazelcast bin folder:

```
java -jar ..\lib\hazelcast-3.12.2.jar com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer
```

This produces the following error:

```
 Dec 20, 2019 8:44:56 AM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractConfigLocator
    INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from the working directory.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
            at com.hazelcast.logging.Log4jFactory.createLogger(Log4jFactory.java:29)
            at com.hazelcast.logging.LoggerFactorySupport$1.createNew(LoggerFactorySupport.java:32)
                ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                ...
```

I see that Hazelcast needs log4j version 1.2.17 so i downloaded that from maven and put it in a folder. I then ran the following:

```
 java -cp ..\..\log4j\log4j-1.2.17.jar -jar ..\lib\hazelcast-3.12.2.jar com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer
```

However, I have read that you can't specify the classpath and the jar in the same statement. The hazelcast jars do not contain the log4j jar file. It seems that they should when packaged.

Can anyone help with this please.

Comment: you can try `java -cp ..\..\log4j\log4j-1.2.17.jar;..\lib\hazelcast-3.12.2.jar com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer` (no need to use -jar if you already know the main class name)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that and same error.

Comment: Well the `org.apache.log4j.Logger` class is contained in the log4j jar, you shouldn't have a NoClassDefFoundError. Can you double-check that the folder and file names are correct?

Comment: You're right i had a path issue. Thanks for that. Now i just need to figure out how to tell log4j how to get the config file.

Comment: If you submit it as an answer then i'll tick

Answer (score 0):

In order to tell log4j how to get the config file, you must add the following line in the config file:

```
    <property name="log4j2.configuration">/path/to/properties/log4j2.properties</property>
```

so it looks like this:

```
  <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j</property>
        <property name="log4j2.configuration">/path/to/properties/log4j2.properties</property>
  </properties>
```

Then you have to edit the log4j2.properties file, as stated in the documentation: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#logging-configuration